# How to compare String with case insensitivity, in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I compare two string in Dart, with case insensitivity?

For example, I have this list:

```
var list = ['Banana', 'apple'];
```

And I would like to sort it such that `apple` is before `Banana`.

End result:

```
['apple', 'Banana'];
```

Answer (score 60):

There's no built in way to compare strings case-insensitive in dart ([as @lrn answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789962/3191896)).

If you only want to compare strings case-insensitive, I would go with declaring the following method somewhere in a common place:

```
bool equalsIgnoreCase(String? string1, String? string2) {
  return string1?.toLowerCase() == string2?.toLowerCase();
}
```

Example:

```
equalsIgnoreCase("ABC", "abc"); // -> true
equalsIgnoreCase("123" "abc");  // -> false
equalsIgnoreCase(null, "abc");  // -> false
equalsIgnoreCase(null, null);   // -> true
```

Answer (score 23):

There is no case-insensitive string compare function (or string equality function for that matter) in Dart. Basically because it's hard, and there is no single good solution that we would want to fix on.

The problem is that the *right* way to do case insensitive comparison is to use the full Unicode case-folding (http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding) together with a (probably locale-specific) ordering of the resulting Unicode characters. Unicode characters may take up multiple code points, and can have different representations, so you probably also want to do other Unicode normalizations.

So, it's horribly complicated and requires a fairly large table.

Great if you already have a full Unicode library, less great if you want to compile to small JavaScript code.

Even if you just use ASCII, you still have to figure out what you want the ordering to be. Is `Z` <  `^`? (As ASCII codes, they are). Is `^` < `a`? Again, as ASCII codes, they are. But you probably don't want `Z` < `a` in case-insensitive comparison, so for consistency, you need to convert to either upper or lower case, and which one you pick will change how `a` and `^` compares to each other.

The `collection` package has a [compareAsciiUpperCase](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/collection/1.9.1/collection/compareAsciiUpperCase.html) function (and similar for lower case), and `package:quiver` has a `compareIgnoreCase` function that just does `toLowerCase()` on both arguments.
You can use that as:

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";
...
   list.sort(compareAsciiUpperCase);
```

Comment: "there is no single good solution that we would want to fix on" -- this does a pretty good job: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 15):

One way to do it, you can upper case your strings in the sort() method:

```
list.sort((a, b) => a.toUpperCase().compareTo(b.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: Note if you do it this way, `['B', 'b']` and `['b', 'B']` will both be considered sorted (modern browsers use a stable sort). Also, you incur the cost of uppercasing each string many times, which can be very expensive.

Comment: @Schism This should solve your case.                                          list.sort((a, b) => a.toUpperCase() != b.toUpperCase() ? a.toUpperCase().compareTo(b.toUpperCase()) : a.compareTo(b));

Comment: @Schism definitely looking for other ways to do it. Care to provide an answer?

Comment: (Just for the record, browser sorting is not guaranteed to be stable, not even in the most recent browsers).

Answer (score 14):

You can create an extension function:

```dart
extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool containsIgnoreCase(String secondString) => this.toLowerCase().contains(secondString.toLowerCase());

  //bool isNotBlank() => this != null && this.isNotEmpty;
}
```

Usage:

```dart
if ("abcd".containsIgnoreCase("AB")) {
    //true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Google's own [quiver strings](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) package. It has a [equalsIgnoreCase](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.strings/equalsIgnoreCase.html) function. And here is its implementation:

**When null is allowed:**

```dart
bool equalsIgnoreCase(String? a, String? b) =>
    (a == null && b == null) ||
    (a != null && b != null && a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase());
```

**When null isn't allowed:**

```dart
bool equalsIgnoreCase(String a, String b) => a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: You could remove the null checks in dart 3, because a String can never be null

Comment: @noah - That's how it's defined here https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.strings/equalsIgnoreCase.html

Comment: String? and String are not the same thing

Comment: @Noah - strange, I copied it raw, it may have changed since then

Comment: It was probably because they were using Dart 2 and not Dart 3

Answer (score 4):

First convert both of the strings to lowercase and then compare them both. Use toLowerCase() function for both of the strings.

```
stirng s1 = "ABC"; string s2 = "abc"; 
if(s1.toLowerCase() == s2.toLowerCase()){
   // whatever you want to implement 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 List found = Names.where(
        (element) => element.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
    .toList();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToLowerCase() on each item and text.

```
list = list.where((x) => x.text.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())).toList();
```

This will make each text in the list lowercase and make the search text lowercase so that both texts are the same case when doing contains function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use work around to solve your issue, simple set all the strings before you compare them to lower case

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the built-in `.toLowerCase()` method **twice**. My use-case was to create a sub-list based on a users' search string, like this:

```
_filteredItems = 
_items.where((element) => element.strTitle.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())).toList();
```

Comment: Please could the down-voters share the reason why so I can learn? The above code works well in my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**For case sensitivity:**

In my case, I need to compare "abc" with  "ABC" and "abc"

`isCaseInsensitiveContains` works for me

```
String myString = "Abc" or  "ABC" or "abc";

"abc".isCaseInsensitiveContains(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue in Javascript, so I use the same solution to compare two strings ignoring case:

1. Convert the string I want to be compared against another to either upper or lowercase
2. Then compare it against the lowercase equivalent of the other string (if it is a constant and I know the value) or also do the same thing I did in Step 1.

Using an extension function:

```dart
extension StringIgnoreCase on String {

  /// function to compare two strings for equality
  bool equalsIgnoreCase(String other) {
    return toLowerCase() == other.toLowerCase();
  }

}
```

In case I know the string I am comparing (a constant value), I would do something like this:

**Using Switch:**

```dart
Color getColorsByStatus(String status) {

  switch (status.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'out for delivery':
      return Colors.red;
    default:
      return Colors.blue;
  }

}
```

**Using If-Else**

```dart
Color getColorsByStatus(String status) {

  if (status.toLowerCase() == 'out for delivery') {
    return Colors.red;
  } else {
    return Colors.blue;
  }

}
```

Where status could be anything; Out of delivery, OUT OF DELIVERY, or even Out Of Delivery

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me!

```dart
extension CusomList on List {
  containsInsensitive(String value) {
    return map((v) => v.toLowerCase()).toList().contains(value.toLowerCase());
  }
}

void main() {
  List<String> list = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Melancia'];

  bool existe = list.containsInsensitive('apple');
  print(existe);
}
```